# Add new column of dictionary values to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-structures, merge

The goal of this is to merge these two structures together:
1. Dictionary of key:value pairs (string1 : string2) -- call it c_dict.
2. Pandas DataFrames, where one of the columns contains a subset of c_dict.keys(). Let's refer to this dataframe as c_df.

I want the final structure to be a DataFrame where string 2 from the dictionary is added as an extra column to c_df.

For example:

```
    c_dict = { 'A' : 'aaa', 'B' : 'bbb', 'C' : 'ccc' }
    print(c_df)

      col1 col2 col3
     0 A    43   55
     1 B    59   88
```

And then the final product would be:

```
       col1 col2 col3 col4
     0  A    43   55  aaa
     1  B    59   88  bbb
```

Answer (score 5):

By using `map`

```
df['col4']=df.col1.map(c_dict)
df

  col1  col2  col3 col4
0    A    43    55  aaa
1    B    59    88  bbb
```

Or, using `replace`:

`replace`:

```
df['col4'] = df.col1.replace(c_dict)
df

  col1  col2  col3 col4
0    A    43    55  aaa
1    B    59    88  bbb
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to type convert your `col1` to `string` type. You can do something like

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(str)
```

for that